# codeigniter не грузит файлы

Tags: php, codeigniter

код view:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>user/">
    <ul>
          <li>
              <label>
                   <input type="text" name="st-image-1">
              </label>
          </li>
          <li>
              <label>
                   <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
              </label>
          </li>
          <li>
              <input type="submit" name="download">
          </li>
      </ul>
</form>
```

код контроллера:

```
if ( $this->input->post('download') ) {
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 2000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') )
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('tmp', 'success');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_userdata('tmp', array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()));
    }
}`
```

загрузка не выполняется и выводит ошибку "The upload path does not appear to be valid.". Но я путь как в мануале указал. Папка существует

Comment: Как в мануале это хорошо, а сама папка `./uploads` сушествует? а права доступа у вас(процесса) к ней есть?

Comment: @E_p папка существует. Может не та дерриктория.. расположил в папке приложения, т.е. application. Права есть

Comment: @E_p поставил путь `./` все равно не работает и выдает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads/';
```

При этом папка uploads должна находиться в одной папке с index.php на одном уровне.